# 1&1 booting policy

Tags: web-hosting

Does anyone know what the parameters are for One&one booting policy for their control panel?

In that it seems a rather short period of time before you get before being kicked out of One&one and then have to login again, which takes ages.

Does it work by a certain amount of inactivity or is there just a set amount of time you can stay logged in before it boots you?

Either way, is there a way to override this? I'm in the process of a lengthy transfer of sites (away from one&one) and it's so frustrating to have to go through the long... slow login several times a day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use 1&1 (moved to a mixture of self hosting and Fasthosts)

I asked their Tech support, they said it was a default in their system and there was nothing they could do about it unfortunately - however that was some time ago, so id suggest calling them just on the off-chance they have made it editable.

Comment: Yes, I believe you need to contact them and you can ask their support team to check and solve your issue. :)